# HTTPClient post from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httpclient, multipart

I'm trying to integrate Zoho viewer:

```
clnt = HTTPClient.new
@zoho_link = clnt.post('http://viewer.zoho.com/api/view.do', {:apikey => 'd4a361ce621000000000000', :file => File.new('/home/jon/Desktop/data.csv')})
```

I already have data in a variable and I want to pass it as a multipart post parameter. How can I make this work without creating a data.csv file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [StringIO](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/classes/StringIO.html) thusly:

```
require 'stringio'
clnt = HTTPClient.new
@zoho_link = clnt.post('http://viewer.zoho.com/api/view.do', {:apikey => 'd4a361ce621000000000000', :file => StringIO.new(your_string)})
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing right direction! Full solution would be:


virtual_file = StringIO.new(my_string);  
def virtual_file.path; 'data.csv'; end  
clnt = HTTPClient.new  
@zoho_link = clnt.post('http://viewer.zoho.com/api/view.do', {:apikey => 'd4a361ce621712b8d23f74cac008eb20', :file => virtual_file})